# Crowdsale contract, Problems when compiling with truffle,

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Near the top under the first constructor,  line 55 says "Warning: This declaration shadows an existing declaration." and line 57 says "Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "Recipient" or "Recipient"?"

Unsure what to do cannot find a similar situation online.

```
     constructor (address payable Recipient) public{ = 
         administrator = msg.sender;
         Recipient = _Recipient; =
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assignment is in reverse

```
Recipient = _Recipient
```

You probably want something like this instead (assuming you have a local variabled declared called _Recipient

```
_Recipient = Recipient
```